# A verb in English that would mean "to win in the court"

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb in English that would mean "to win in the court"?

For example, both Johnson and Gregson claimed their rights on one patch of land in Arizona. They took this case to the court and the judge decided that that patch of land should belong to Gregson. So one would say:

> Gregson has finally [the verb] that patch of land.

or better (if it's possible in English):

> Gregson has finally [the verb] that patch of land from Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of legal proceedings, a dispute, or a consideration between parties, you can say the following:

> Gregson has finally *been* ***awarded*** that patch of land.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*award*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/award):

> **2** : to give by judicial decree or after careful consideration
>   // The jury *awarded* damages to the defendant.
>   // *award* a contract

Note that you need the auxiliary verb *been* in order for it to work in your sentence.

You would not add *from Johnson* here, but it would be understood from the context.

---

Alternatively, a simpler verb, that isn't quite as specific, but whose meaning would also be clear in this context, and where *from Johnson* could remain, is **won**:

> Gregson has finally **won** that patch of land from Johnson.

You can use *won* here because people talk about winning and losing court cases. *Win* also often blurs the line between the circumstance and the result.

For instance, these would all be considered fine:

> I **won** the lottery and was *given* a million dollars.
>   I **won** a million dollars *in* the lottery.
>   I **won** the heavy-weight title *from* Tyson.

---

Personally, I would not say that you won something *from someone*. To me, it's more natural to simply say that you won something—or that you *took* something from someone. But I believe that's just my personal opinion. Objectively speaking, I think it's common to hear people say (at least informally) that somebody won something *from someone*. So, that shouldn't be a concern here.

Answer (score 1):

While "been awarded" is good, in this case a longer sentence may be clearer.

> Gregson has finally won his lawsuit with Johnson over  that patch of land.

or

> Gregson has finally won his lawsuit with Johnson and was awarded that patch of land.

This makes it very clear that the "win" was in a court case, and the second makes clear that the land was awarded to Gregson.  (In the first he might merely have gotten a sum of money as damages, or some other outcome, depending on the suit.)

Answer (score 0):

recover

[How to Recover Money From a Lawsuit](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/recover-money-lawsuit-16247.html)

> However, courts do not contact defendants to collect money. If a
>   defendant does not have any assets, then you might not **recover** any
>   money.

---

> If you file a lawsuit and win, you'll be entitled to **recover** money
>   damages.